# Select from XElement with where statement using linq

Tags: linq-to-xml, xelement

I have and XElement object that was built up from an XML looking like this:

```
<Root>
  <Oppurtunities>
    <Oppurtunity>
      <Title> Account Manager</Title>
      <Company>Company name</Company>
      <Location>Boston</Location>
      <EndDate>2013-04-11</EndDate>
      <c>acce</c>
      <id>MNYN-95ZL8L</id>
      <Description>This is a detailed description...</Description>
    </Oppurtunity>
```

Now I need to get the description value from a specific Oppurtunity node, meaning I want to get description from where the id is specific. I need to do something like this:

```
//My XElement object is called oppurtunities
oppurtunities = new XElement((XElement)Cache["Oppurtunities"]);

string id = Request.QueryString["id"];

//I want to do something like this but of course this is not working
var description = (from job in oppurtunities
                              .Element("Oppurtunities")
                              .Element("Oppurtunity")
                              .Element("Description")
                              where job.Element("id") == id).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move `.Element("Description")` further in your query, to allow `id` condition work:

```
//I want to do something like this but of course this is not working
var description = (from job in oppurtunities
                              .Element("Oppurtunities")
                              .Elements("Oppurtunity")
                   where job.Element("id") == id
                   select job.Element("Description")).SingleOrDefault()
```

To compare `Element("id")` as a string use `(string)XElement` conversion - it's gonna work even when `<id>` won't be found:

```
where (string)job.Element("id") == id
```

Using `XElement.Value` will throw `NullReferenceException` in that situation.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I just needed to set where job.Element("id").Value since it's compared to a string.